# In the future if we needed to send a micronero or piconero, wouldn't fees cost more than that value?

Tags: transaction-fees, scalability

How can someone send a micronero or piconero in the future if a micronero = $1. And fees per transaction is more than this. What are some solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If the fees go over the transaction amount it would use the rest of your wallet balance to cover for that as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

> How can someone send a micronero or piconero in the future if a micronero = $1

Fiat (USD/XMR) exchange rate has no bearing to the question.

> And fees per transaction is more than this. What are some solutions to this problem?

The fee amount in a tx is not deducted from the destination amount, it's a separate field in the tx. So regardless of how small (or large) amount you're sending, your wallet (as always) has to have enough funds to cover both the tx fee and the sum of all the destination outputs.